# Splitting React components into separate files

Tags: javascript, class, components, reactjs

This seems to be a common question, I'm finding a lot of people asking it and the responses are all very different and seem to be a bit hit and miss. I've watched various video tutorials, read plenty of tutorials, and the documentation. But alas it seems React is moving faster than the writers can keep up with. Or I'm just misunderstanding.

I want to create each component in a separate file, where logical to do so. I have React working, but am unable to work out how to import and use additional files. I don't know if this is because Chrome will not load in files when not on a web server (local test dev), or if I'm just going about it all wrong.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Test One</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="rootNode"></div>
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my main.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Square = require('../components/square.jsx').square;

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <h1>Hello React!</h1>
        <Square />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('rootNode')

);
```

This works fine if I don't try to use Square also.

This is my square.jsx:

```
class Square extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <p>Square</p>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = {
    square: Square
};
```

Babel create the bundle.js fine, no errors. Chrome throws the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function,
>   class) not yet supported outside strict mode

I have tried the following also for square, along with many other things, all lost from the undo queue:

```
import React from 'react';

class Square extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <p>Square</p>
        )
    }
}

export default Square;
```

All help appreciated. React seems to make sense aside from separating out the class files.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Also tried:

```
var {Component} = React;

class Square extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <p>Square</p>
        )
    }
}

window.Square = Square;
```

And if it helps here is the Gulp file:

```
var vendors = [
    'react'
];

gulp.task('vendors', function () {
    var stream = browserify({
        debug: false,
        require: vendors
    });

    stream.bundle()
        .pipe(source('./src/main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/bundle.js'));

    return stream;
});
```

And the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reacttestone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Testing React Components",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.2",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "react": "^0.14.2",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Myself",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your es6 example of exporting like `export default Square` should work fine. It looks like you've installed babelify but you're not using it in the transform process, hence why the browser is complaining that you're trying to use es6 features outside of strict mode.

If you look at the [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) instructions it says to do something like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('browserify', function () {
    browserify('./src/main.js', { debug: true })
        .transform('babelify', {presets: ['es2015', 'react']})
        .bundle()
        .on('error', gutil.log)
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
});

gulp.task('watch',function() {
    gulp.watch('./src/**/*.js', ['browserify'])
});
```

It looks like you only have `babel-preset-react` installed, you'll need to do `npm i babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev`. Also `babelify` and `babel-preset-react` are fine as `devDependencies`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. That gives me the error: `import React from 'react';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'`

Comment: However I think that is a different issue, so I'm going to mark your answer as the answer.

Comment: If I go with my window.Square = Square; approach I now get: `(let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode`

Comment: @Andrew it seems then that something is still not working as the browser it trying to use es6 features. You can put 'use strict' at the top of your file, however it won't work in much else other than the latest browsers (which have PARTIAL es6 support). I recommend you either try and get that babelify bit to work, or switch to the superior webpack bundler

Comment: @Andrew see edited post, untested but from what I read that would hopefully be working

Comment: Tweaked it a bit so gulp runs, but I'm still getting errors in the browser. I'll look into web pack. Cheers.