# Modules exported using es6 syntax for the browser

Tags: ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I have a module `module-A` which has the following in `index.js`

```
import SomeModule from './lib/some-module'
import AnotherModule from './lib/another-module'

module.exports ={
 SomeModule: SomeModule, 
 AnotherModule: AnotherModule
}
```

I then use this `module-A` from another `module-B`:

```
import SomeModule from `module-A`
```

I now want to build `module-B` for the browser, so I use `browserify` from the `module-B` cwd: [I am using babel 6.0]

```
browserify index.js -t [ babelify  --presets [ es2015  ] ]
```

This throws an error as

```
import SomeModule from './lib/some-module'
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

Is there anyway I can export modules using es6 export and import syntax and yet build properly for the browser.

Comment: Do you have [babel-preset-es2015](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/) installed?

Comment: Yes, it was installed.

Comment: Are you trying to load module from `node_modules`? Usually, modules there considered as built and doesn't get transpilled by default

Comment: I am doing `npm link` from `module-A` and `npm link module-A` from `module-B`. I also tried installing from local repo like `npm install ..path/to/module/A`. Both of these approaches gave the above behaviour.

I then added the `browser` field  in the `package.json` file. The transpiled code from `module-A` was made available in the `browser.js` file. But in this case, any inner modules required from `some-module` is not resolvable from the `module-B` build scope. Please let me know if you want to have a sample project, I can set ip up for you..

Comment: As a workaround, I have transpiled my `module-A` using babel (entire source directory) and then at the end of the pipeline, I have ended up using browserify. Works for now, would like to better (if any)  alternatives.

Comment: I don't think you should mix commonjs with ES6 module syntax.